# Getting a random record from a set of results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
@user_id = params[:user_id]
@picture = Picture.scoped
if @user_id.present?
    @picture = @picture.where("user_id not in (?)", params[:user_id])
end
@picture = @picture.rand(@picture.count).first

respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to(@picture) }
    format.json { render :json => @picture }
end
```

I get the following error:
**NoMethodError in PicturesController#next**
private method `rand' called for []:ActiveRecord::Relation

Instead of

```
@picture = @picture.rand(@picture.count).first
```

I also tried

```
@picture = Picture.offset(rand(Picture.count)).first
```

and get this error instead:
**ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in PicturesController#next**
Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0.6704131293122307' at line 1: SELECT  `pictures`.* FROM `pictures` LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0.6704131293122307

What am I doing wrong, or how do I go about getting a random record from the array of results?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

convert rand result to integer like this:

```
@picture = Picture.offset(rand(Picture.count).to_i).first
```

Answer (score 2):

In ruby 1.9.2, you can just do:

```
@picture.sample
```

Comment: didn't it require that @picture is collection of rows already fetched from database? if he only has to return one row, fetching all and then selecting one is not good ;)

Comment: @Andrian I agree. I just though of a replacement of his troublematic line.

Comment: This works, but as per the comments I marked Adrian's as the best answer.  Thanks, guys!