# Get random records from a has_many field in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a model :

```
class HotelTheme < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :hotels
end
```

I want to get 6 hotels using a random.

I tried:

```
@hotelTheme.hotels.rand(6)
```

But it fails, any idea?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting a random record from a set of results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004820/getting-a-random-record-from-a-set-of-results)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use following syntax:

```
@hotelTheme.hotels.order("RANDOM()").limit(6) #for MySQL RAND()
```

`RANDOM()` is a SQL built-in function and it's works slow on big tables. 
Also take a look at [randumb gem](https://github.com/spilliton/randumb).

Comment: Wouldn't it be the `order` that would make this slow for large tables, not the `RANDOM()`? Not sure your answer makes this quite clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the overhead of returning all `hotel`s when you only want six you could do

```
@hotelTheme.hotels.shuffle[0..5]
```

But if your `hotel_theme` has loads of `hotel`s this is probably quite a bad idea.